# python filtering a list of combinations

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a pretty unique problem here i’ve been racking my brain trying to figured out a succinct and functional solution to. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

I’m trying to filter a list of tuples of dictionaries. I know this sounds complicated, but it makes sense I promise.

To visualize, each internal dictionary represents a type of ball.  I have 4 boxes. Each will contain a single ball. A set of 4 boxes is represented by a tuple with length 4. I had to find every unique combination of balls in a set of 4 boxes. So if I had 6 balls, I have 4^6 unique combinations and therefore tuples in the list. After using itertools, I have this list of combinations (list of tuples) with different combinations of balls (dictionaries). Now that I have this epic list of unique combinations, I need to filter out the ones I want to process.  I want to filter out only combinations (tuples) with a ball of, say ‘type1’ in box 1 (tuple index 1) AND  type 0 in box 3 for example. The result would be a list of tuples of dictionaries, or a list of combinations where certain types of balls where in certain boxes.

I’m seeing the best way of input being a dictionary such as {1:’type1’,3:’type3’} for the example above. The input dictionary would have most be {1:_ , 2: _ , 3: _ , 4:_} of course. And if anyone has other suggestions on how to pass these filter options in I’m very open to suggestions.

I’m envisioning a list comprehension with a lambda function with an AND in it? Can’t seem to make anything work, though.

Some of you guys are wizards with list/dictionary comprehensions and matching the internal functions to get what you want in a succinct line of functionality. If you answer this could you please tell me how it works and why it works. Trying to learn from the brain trust.

What I have so far:

```
def config_filter(allConfigs,filterOptions,fieldName):
    # fieldName: a string which is the key to the dictionary being looked. In 
    # examples this would be 'type'

    # because the filter options could have any of 1 through 4 options, a list
    # of keys are made. 
    keys = list(filterOptions.keys())

    def zero(): #return unfiltered allConfigs if no options are given
        return allConfigs
    def one():  # use the first key to filter through list items
        return [d for d in allConfigs if filterOptions[keys[0]]==d[keys[0]][fieldName]]
    def two():
        return [d for d in allConfigs if filterOptions[keys[0]]==d[keys[0]][fieldName]
            and filterOptions[keys[1]]==d[keys[1]][fieldName]]
    def three():
        return [d for d in allConfigs if filterOptions[0]==d[keys[0]][fieldName]
            and filterOptions[keys[1]]==d[keys[1]][fieldName] 
            and filterOptions[keys[2]]==d[keys[2]][fieldName]]
    def four():
        return [d for d in allConfigs if filterOptions[keys[0]]==d[keys[0]][fieldName]
            and filterOptions[keys[1]]==d[keys[1]][fieldName] 
            and filterOptions[keys[2]]==d[keys[2]][fieldName]
            and filterOptions[keys[3]]==d[keys[3]][fieldName]]

    options = {0:zero(),1: one(),2: two(),3: three(),4: four()}

    return options[len(filterOptions)]()
```

Comment: Post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I should have added that before. My apologies. The issue i see is not knowing what the dictionary coming in is. The issue with the code above is that when, the function definitions are made, 'keys' index will be out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have done it. but you want a succinct, one sentence one?

here it is:

```
def config_filter(allConfigs, filterOptions, fieldName):
    return [d for d in allConfigs 
              if len([o for o in filterOptions 
                        if d[int(o)-1][fieldName] == filterOptions[o]])
                 == len(filterOptions) ]

l = [({"type":1},{"type":2},{"type":3},{"type":4}),
      ({"type":5},{"type":2},{"type":3},{"type":4}),
      ({"type":5},{"type":2},{"type":6},{"type":4}),
      ({"type":5},{"type":3},{"type":6},{"type":4}),
      ({"type":1},{"type":6},{"type":3},{"type":4}),
      ({"type":1},{"type":2},{"type":5},{"type":4}),
      ({"type":1},{"type":2},{"type":6},{"type":4})]
print(config_filter(l, {}, "type"))
print(config_filter(l, {1:5}, "type"))
print(config_filter(l, {1:5, 3:6}, "type"))
print(config_filter(l, {1:5, 3:6, 2:3}, "type"))
```

Comment: it was kind of working but I was having out of bounds index issues. Your option is exceptionally slick. So you're using a comprehension within a comprehension correct? I understand the outer one. Now if i'm looking at it correctly, a configuration is correct IF the number of filters equaling true == the number of filter options. Thank you so much for spending the time. that was perfect.